# How to create backup of ms access in folder?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access

I want to create backup of ms access database with `.bk` extension with c# code And the backup should automatically save in Day Wise folder like If I click on `backup` today, then it should automatically create back in `Wednesday` Folder. How to do this?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by backup... a copy of the MS Access file / a dump of the data to another file type / something else?  If the former, Can you use the System.IO classes to create a folder and copy the back end?

Comment: copy of database but on the basis of day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backup of MS Access database is a file copy.

Starting from a baseDirectory, with Path.Combine you can build a fullDirectory name containing the baseDirectory and the day. After that you can copy the file (File.Copy) to that directory (eventually using Path.Combine to build a fullPath of the file).
Don't forget to Dispose the connection before copying the file and be sure the no one is using the file when you make the copy.

**EDIT**

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        string baseDirectory = "C:\\Insert\\Your\\Base\\Directory";
        string mdbSourceFilePath = "C:\\Directory\\Of\\mdb\\MyAccessDb.accdb";
        string mdbTargetFileName = "MyAccessDb.bk";

        string fullDirectory = Path.Combine(baseDirectory, DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd"));
        if (!Directory.Exists(baseDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(baseDirectory);
        if (!Directory.Exists(fullDirectory))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(fullDirectory);

        string mdbTargetFilePath = Path.Combine(fullDirectory, mdbTargetFileName);

        File.Copy(mdbSourceFilePath, mdbTargetFilePath);


    }


}
```

Comment: this code is working but it I click again it should replace

Comment: before the copy (File.Copy) you could check if the file exists then, if exists, delete it... I.e. if (File.Exists(mdbTargetFileName)) File.Delete(mdbTargetFileName);

Comment: if (File.Exists(mdbTargetFileName)) File.Delete(mdbTargetFileName); not working